# How to reverse a rotated rectangle?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Say there's a rectangle at (20, 20)(fig. 1), then it's rotated 45 degree (fig. 2), if I just have the rotated rectangle and know it's size and rotated degree, is there a way to reverse the rotation and get the original starting point (20, 20)?

[fig. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRKMP.png)
[fig. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGHN1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

Let point $A$ denote (14,105) and let point $B$ denote (120,70)

You know the angle that $\overline{AB}$ makes with the horizontal.  Therefore, you should be able to add $45^{\circ}$ to that to get the new angle that $\overline{AB}$ makes with the horizontal.

Now you have a ray, emanating from point $B$.  Also, you know the distance of $\overline{AB}$.  Therefore, you know how far to traverse along the ray to identify the original point $A$.

Comment: What if I don't know (120, 70) in fig. 2, can this still be solved?

Comment: @JohnGold If you know the dimensions of the rectangle, then the exact center of the rectangle (120,70) can be determined.  If you don't know the point (120,70), and at least one of the dimensions of the rectangle are unknown, then the original point A can **not** be determined.  To see this, note that point A is determined by **both** (14,105) and the center of the rectangle.  If the center of the rectangle changes, the determination of point A **must change**.